# 3-dimensional triangulations with fixed number of vertices

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, geometry, graph-theory, triangulation

My question is the following:

> Are there triangulations of $S^3$ which (a) are non-degenerate, (b)
> have four vertices, and (c) have no edges of degree two?

---

Here are the definitions.

We use labeled triangulations of $S^3$.  We allow adjacent tetrahedra to share multiple faces. The *degree* of a vertex (or an edge) is the number of tetrahedra connected to it, *counted with multiplicity*.

We only allow *non-degenerate triangulations*.  That is, we require that every edge is embedded (meets two vertices).  Note that this implies that all triangles and tetrahedra are embedded.

However, we do not require out triangulations to be *simplicial* (where a cell is determined by its vertices).  In particular, we allow many edges to share the same two endpoints as vertices.  In this case we distinguish the edges by their labels.  The same applies to triangles and tetrahedra.

There are various moves that can change the configuration to another.  To be concrete, imagine two adjacent tetrahedra defined by vertices $\{a, b, c, d\}$ sharing four faces.  Note that all edges have degree two. Let's call this our "initial configuration".  We can add additional tetrahedra to the initial configuration (maintaining the topology) in various ways.

**0-2 face move:**
Choose a triangle (between two tetrahedra $A$ and $B$) and glue in a pair of tetrahedra ($C$ and $D$) sharing three faces, (and a new vertex: $e$), and their remaining face is glued between let's say the triangle $(a b c)$ and its copy $(a,b,c)$, defining the set now as: $\{a b c d\}$, $\{a b c d\}$, $\{a b c e\}$, $\{a b c e\}$.  This is like inflating a triangle into a sphere and putting a vertex in the middle. The same vertices can define unique triangles and edges. If we would give labels to triangle $(a b c)$ or the other $(a b c)$ they would differ due to their adjacency relation. This move increases the number of vertices.

**1-4 move:**
Choose a tetrahedron.  Add a vertex in the middle of the tetrahedron, connecting it to all the four vertices, splitting the interior into 4 tetrahedra.

**2-3 move**
Choose a face meeting distinct tetrahedra. Add an edge to connect the distant vertices of two adjacent tetrahedra, exchanging a triangular face with an edge.  This turns two tetrahedra into three.

**0-2 edge move:**
Choose two adjacent triangles $(a b c)$, $(a b d)$, and open them up, inserting two tetrahedra $\{a b c d\}$ and $\{a b c d\}$, by creating a copy of $(a b c)$ and $(a b d)$ in the process. The move adds two tetrahedra, a new edge with degree 2, and splits the original [a b] edge into be two with smaller or equal degree than their original. (0-2 edge move)

One could devise other types of moves, adding extra edges, or adding/ removing extra vertices, to change the triangulation into another one.  (Note that all moves can be obtained from the [bistellar flips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachner_moves): the 2-3 and 1-4 moves.)

Comment: You are leaving too many things undefined, like "noncombinatorial" and "degree."

Comment: Thanks, the question is expanded. Let me know please if it is not clear.

Comment: It seems to me that once you have glued 2 tetrahedra on $S^3$ that share 4 faces, the whole $S^3$ is covered, so it is no more possible to glue another tetrahedron. Same as when gluing 2 triangles on $S^2$, or 2 segments on $S^1$. Is there any misunderdtanding?

Comment: Imagine, that you expand two adjacent  triangles by connecting their distant vertices with a link, then you create two new tetrahedron (sharing two faces), the other 2-2 faces will be connected to the original 2 triangles and to a copy of them. This "move" adds 2 new tetrahedra, 2 new links, 4 new triangles and zero vertices. But one if the new link is of degree 2. So I am interested in increasing the number of simplices , but finding a situation without any edge degree 2.

Comment: @Kregnach I really don't understand how this is possible, sorry. If you want to clarify the question, add a diagram, or at least name all the points.

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni please tell me what do dou think my question lacks, and I will expand it. I would like to avoid editing it infinite times (I already did it a few times)

Comment: @Kregnach It lacks a way for the reader to understand without ambiguity. You could name all the vertices. And add different names for triangles or tetrahedra that have the same vertices - something like $ABCD_1$ and $ABCD_2$, to distinguish 2 tetrahedra that have the same vertices but not the same interior.

Comment: Please let me now if it's clearer.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Notably because you mentioned Pachner moves. Not sure I wil be able to answer, though. Thanks.